# Using 2, 2, 10 and 11, make 12

Tags: number-theory

Given the numbers $2, 2, 10$ and $11$. Can we form $12$ with using each number exactly once and using standard operators. You are not allowed to use concatenation: $10+\frac{22}{11}=12$ is not allowed. I've been able to make every number up to $300$, but I haven't been able to do $12$, yikes. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: We can repeat numbers?

Comment: I don't think so. We must use them all.

Answer (score 3):

$$(11-\frac{10}{2})\cdot 2=12$$

Answer (score 2):

$$2 \cdot (2-10+11)!=12$$
where ! denotes factorial.